# Loop an array in my own order

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, php-5.4

i was displaying a list of stores to get the flags.

But i want to display it in my own order so, as far as i know, i makes the loop as normal:

```
  <?php foreach ($_stores as $_store): ?>
        <?php
        // do not print flag for the current store
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() == $_store->getId()) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!in_array($_store->getId(), array(1, 2, 9, 16, 18, 21, 22, 23))) {
            continue;
        }
```

There i check to don`t show the current store, and to check only the stores that i enter manually into the array.

But now i wants to get the stores in my own order.

I show it with this code:

```
< li>
        <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
        <?php
        $store_id = $_store->getId();
        $logo_src = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src_small', $store_id)
        ?>
        <img class="mini-icon" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') ?>frontend/default/DESIGN/<?php echo $logo_src ?>" />
        <img class="mini-lang" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/flags/flag_$country.png") ?>" />
        <span class="span-lang" title="<?php echo $_store->getTranslatedName() ?>"><?php echo $_store->getTranslatedName() ?></span>
        </a>

    </li>
```

EDIT
My own order was: 1 - 2 -21 -23 -22 -16 -18

I did it on BE -> store_views -> store_order

Comment: Where does foreach loop end? Have you printed stores within foreach?

Comment: pls also include "What order is expected and what order it shows" in your question

Comment: I'm sorry, i make it now, but its done with store_order BE config.
Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento already has a `sort_order` field for stores in the backend so why not use that?

```
$allowedStores = array(1, 2, 9, 16, 18, 21, 22, 23);

$_stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect(array('name', 'code', 'store_id'))
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $allowedStores))
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('neq' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())) // filter current store
    ->setOrder('sort_order','ASC'); // order by backend sortorder

<?php foreach ($_stores as $_store): ?>
   // do here whatever you wanna do
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It would be best to add this logic not in the phtml file but in a custom block or helper class

Comment: Thanks!
I'm new on magento, and don't know the sort_order on BE.
Thanks for all